# Xamarin - I want to Update Xmarain.forms to 193 in vs 2015

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

please developers I want to **`Update **Xmarain.forms** to 193  in vs 2015`** 
Because when i create new projet i get errors 
when i update the project from Nuget the error solved 
so i want to Update **Xmarain.forms** to 193  in vs 2015

Comment: We'll need to see those errors to solve them.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use NuGet to get latest stable release for **Xamarin.Forms**, Keep in your mind you need to update all projects in your solution that reference **Xamarin.Forms**, right now latest Stable release is 2.3.4.244.

you need to do the following:

Project --> Manage NuGet Packages --> Installed --> Xamrin.Forms --> Choose Version(2.3.3.193) --> Update

for more info about NuGet Xamarin.forms check the following link:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms/